# How to find every customers' favourite category with a query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in MS Access which looks basically like this:

```
Table Name : Customer_Categories

+----------------------+------------+-------+
| Email                | CategoryID | Count |
+----------------------+------------+-------+
| jim@example.com      |         10 |     4 |
+----------------------+------------+-------+
| jim@example.com      |          2 |     1 |
+----------------------+------------+-------+
| simon@example.com    |          5 |     2 |
+----------------------+------------+-------+
| steven@example.com   |         10 |    16 |
+----------------------+------------+-------+
| steven@example.com   |          5 |     3 |
+----------------------+------------+-------+
```

In this table there are ≈ 350,000 records. The characteristics are this:

- Duplicate values for Email, CategoryID and Count
- Count refers to the number of times this customer has ordered from this category

### What I want

I want to create a table that consists of a unique email address along with the CategoryID this customer has purchased from the most.

So the above example would be:

```
+----------------------+------------+
| Email                | CategoryID |
+----------------------+------------+
| jim@example.com      |         10 |
+----------------------+------------+
| simon@example.com    |          5 |
+----------------------+------------+
| steven@example.com   |         10 |
+----------------------+------------+
```

### What I have tried

I have written a query that achieves what I want:

```
SELECT main.Email, (SELECT TOP 1 CategoryID
    FROM Customer_Categories
    WHERE main.Email = Email
    GROUP BY CategoryID
    ORDER BY MAX(Count) DESC, CategoryID ASC) AS Category
FROM Customer_Categories AS main
GROUP BY main.Email;
```

This works a treat and does exactly what I want. It returns results in around 8 seconds. However I need this data in a new table because I then want to update another table with the categoryID. When I add `INTO Customer_Favourite_Categories` after the sub-query to add this data to a new table rather than just return the result set and run the query it never finishes. I've left it running for about 45 minutes and it does nothing.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Just as a test, can you export the result to a file and check the size and the time of creation? Perhaps Access is paging the result set

Comment: @xanatos I couldn't export it because if I tried to do anything with the result set it crashed Access. However we worked out the problem. When we put an index on Customer_Categories.Email everything worked perfectly. Customer_Categories was just a temporary table so I hadn't thought to index it. Didn't realise it would make such a difference!

Answer (score 2):

If `select into` doesn't work, use `insert into`:

```
create table Customer_Favorite_Categories (
    email <email type>,
    FavoriteCategory <CategoryId type>
);


insert into Customer_Favorite_Categories
  SELECT main.Email, (SELECT TOP 1 CategoryID
      FROM Customer_Categories
      WHERE main.Email = Email
      GROUP BY CategoryID
      ORDER BY MAX(Count) DESC, CategoryID ASC) AS Category
  FROM Customer_Categories AS main
  GROUP BY main.Email;
```

Comment: Still nothing. I was talking over lunch to a colleague and he thinks it may actually be producing a lot more records than I think. I need to investigate further...

Comment: @MrMisterMan . . . Do you have an index on `Customer_Categories(email, CategoryId)`?  That might help.

Comment: Me and a colleague have just worked out that it was indeed the lack of index on the Email field that was causing the problem. Since you suggested it here if you put that in your answer I can mark is as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Distinct(Email),Max(CategoryID )

 FROM Customer_Categories group by Email
```

Comment: Thanks @Kanith but I need the CategoryID that corresponds with the MAX(Count) of that CategoryID, not the highest categoryID.

Answer (score 0):

I use sub-queries for this quite frequently.  Your query in "What I have tried" is close, but just a little off in syntax.  Something like the following should get what you are after.  Count is in square-brackets since it's a reserved word in SQL.  The spacing I use in my SQL is conventional, so edit to your liking.

```
SELECT Email,
  CategoryID
FROM MyTable AS m,
  (
      SELECT Email,
        MAX( [Count] ) AS mc
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY Email
  ) AS f
WHERE m.Email = f.Email
AND m.[Count] = f.mc;
```